# GamePlayKit GKObstacleGraph save and load

Tags: gameplay-kit

Can GKObstacleGraph be saved to a file and loaded from there ? 
I cant find anything on this.

I would love to save and load precalculated graphs for my levels.

I have tried so far

```
 NSArray * obstacles = [SKNode obstaclesFromNodePhysicsBodies:arrayOfBodies];
 _graph = [GKObstacleGraph graphWithObstacles:obstacles bufferRadius:[(BaseUnit *)[_units firstObject] size].width/2];
[NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:_graph toFile:@"/Users/roma/Desktop/myGraph.graph"];
```

But this is what I got:

> -[GKObstacleGraph encodeWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6180000432d0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`GKObstacleGraph` is a subclass of [`GKGraph`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/gameplaykit/gkgraph), which (*as of macOS 10.12, iOS 10, and tvOS 10*) declares conformance to the [`NSCoding`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nscoding) protocol. That means you can serialize one to data or a file (and deserialize to create an instance from a file) using [`NSKeyedArchiver`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nskeyedarchiver) (and [NSKeyedUnarchiver](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nskeyedunarchiver)) just like you can for any other object that supports `NSCoding`.

For general info on archiving (which applies to any `NSCoding`-compatible class), see Apple's [Archives and Serializations Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Archiving/Archiving.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000047i).

Also, in Xcode 8 (when deploying to macOS 10.12, iOS 10, or tvOS 10), you can create `GKGraph`s in a visual editor to go along with your SpriteKit scenes. When you do that, you use the [GKScene](https://developer.apple.com/reference/gameplaykit/gkscene) class to load both the SpriteKit scene and the GK objects (which can include not just pathfinding graphs, but also entity/component info) from the `.sks` file Xcode writes.

---

In older OS versions, the `GKGraph` family doesn't support `NSCoding`. However, all the information you need to reconstruct a `GKObstacleGraph` is publicly accessible. So you could implement your own serialization by reading a graph's buffer radius and list of obstacles, and reading each obstacle's list of vertices. Write that info to a file however you like... then when you want to reconstruct a graph, create `GKPolygonObstacle`s from the vertices you saved, and create a new `GKObstacleGraph` from those obstacles and your saved buffer radius.

Comment: I tried to use NSAtchiever (not keyed) and it throwed an exception on me :-(

Comment: Same for KeyedArchiever

Comment: Are you on iOS 9 / tvOS 9 / OS X 10.11? Archiving support was added to the `GKGraph` class cluster only in this year's releases (iOS 10 / tvOS 10 / macOS 10.12).

Comment: I am on 10.11, Oh so you mean if I will change my Target to 10.12 I will get archiver? 
Could you please Confirm that on 10.12 it works ?

Well Then I will have to wait till the release...

Comment: Then it will also conform to NSCopying ? as documented ?

Comment: About your edit: I couldn't find a Buffer radius Setter Method

Comment: Seems Like Sierra will be released in 5 days... then I will play with this.
Honestly I can afford supporting sierra only it is fine by me